# AWS with Terraform - Filtering public/private subnets (without relying on tags)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

**Request:**

I would like to spin an AWS ALB - For that I need at least two subnets in two different Availability Zones.

(Terraform shows a very explicit error in case we forget - see Error #1 Below).

I would like to check the current number of public subnets that I have in the relevant VPC, and make sure its a least 2.

**My Attempt:**

For that I'll calculate:

```
number_of_public_subnets_to_create  = "${2 - length(data.aws_subnet_ids.customer_a_public_subnets.ids)}"
```

For the calculation above - Terraform have 2 data sources types:  [aws_subnet](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet.html) and [aws_subnet_ids](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet_ids.html).

In case the subnets are tagged - We can use the `aws_subnet_ids` data source  and add a simple filter like this:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "customer_a_public_subnets" {
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.my-customer_a-vpc.id}"
  tags {
      Tier = "Public"
  }
}
```

**My Question:**

But what if the subnets doesn't contain a "Public/Private" tags?

Is there simple solution for that (maybe a common filter on the `aws_subnet` data source)?

---

Error #1:

> Error creating application Load Balancer: ValidationError: At least
>   two subnets in two different Availability Zones must be specified.

Comment: Have you figured out a way to solve the Public/Private filtering ?
If so, can you share ?

Comment: @Auyer I posted my answer if you still need the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I understand you might have spent much time on filtering the subnets based on public/private.
According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeSubnets.html), there is a filter - `map-public-ip-on-launch` to check whether a public IPv4 is assigned on launch or not.

So we can get the public/private subnets as below.

```
data "aws_subnets" "private" {
  filter {
    name = "vpc-id"
    values = [
      data.aws_vpc.shared.id
    ]
  }

  filter {
    name = "map-public-ip-on-launch"
    values = [false]
  }
}

data "aws_subnets" "public" {
  filter {
    name = "vpc-id"
    values = [
      data.aws_vpc.shared.id
    ]
  }

  filter {
    name = "map-public-ip-on-launch"
    values = [true]
  }
}
```

Then you can use the `private` and `public` to retrieve the subnet ids.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer using a filter on `"map-public-ip-on-launch"` didn't work for me, but fortunately the names of my subnets (created by the `"terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"` module) contained `public` and `private` so I could filter on the name.

```
data "aws_subnets" "private" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.base.id]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["*private*"]
  }
}

data "aws_subnets" "public" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.base.id]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["*public*"]
  }
}
```